# Find which Parallel ForEach thread threw exception

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, dotnetnuke

Hello and thank you in advance for your advice,

I have a Parallel For-each Loop which is sending out bulk emails. What I want to know is how to find out which thread threw an SmtpException.  I would like to know which email address it could not send to.

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            List<string> emailList;
            List<string> invalidList = new List<string> { };
            string[] attachments = { };
            if (rbListType.Items.FindByValue("CSV").Selected)
            {
                emailList = tbEmailTo.Text.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
                int count = 0;
                int total = emailList.Count;
                RadRadialGauge1.Scale.Max = total;
                RadRadialGauge1.Scale.Min = 0;
                //for (int i = 0; i < emailList.Count; i++)
                //{
                //    if (emailList[i].Contains('<'))
                //    {
                //        if (!Mail.IsValidEmailAddress(emailList[i].ToString().Split('<')[1].Replace(">", ""), PortalId))
                //        {
                //            emailList.RemoveAt(i);
                //            invalidList.Add(emailList[i].ToString());
                //        }
                //    }
                //    else
                //    {
                //        if (!Mail.IsValidEmailAddress(emailList[i].ToString(), PortalId))
                //        {
                //            emailList.RemoveAt(i);
                //            invalidList.Add(emailList[i].ToString());
                //        }
                //    }
                //}

                Parallel.ForEach(emailList, email =>
                {
                    Mail.SendMail(tbEmailFrom.Text, email.ToString(), tbEmailCC.Text, tbEmailBC.Text, tbReplyTo.Text, DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.MailPriority.Normal,
                        tbSubject.Text, MailFormat.Html, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, tbEmailBody.Text, attachments, smtpServer, smtpAuthentication, smtpUsername, smtpPassword, false);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

                });

                RadRadialGauge1.Pointer.Value = count;

            }
            if (rbListType.Items.FindByValue("Excel").Selected)
            {
                emailList = tbEmailTo.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
                int count = 0;
                int total = emailList.Count;
                RadRadialGauge1.Scale.Max = total;
                RadRadialGauge1.Scale.Min = 0;
                //for (int i = 0; i < emailList.Count; i++)
                //{
                //    if (emailList[i].Contains('<'))
                //    {
                //        if (!Mail.IsValidEmailAddress(emailList[i].ToString().Split('<')[1].Replace(">", ""), PortalId))
                //        {
                //            emailList.RemoveAt(i);
                //            invalidList.Add(emailList[i].ToString());
                //        }
                //    }
                //    else
                //    {
                //        if (!Mail.IsValidEmailAddress(emailList[i].ToString(), PortalId))
                //        {
                //            emailList.RemoveAt(i);
                //            invalidList.Add(emailList[i].ToString());
                //        }
                //    }
                //}


                Parallel.ForEach(emailList, email =>
                {

                    Mail.SendMail(tbEmailFrom.Text, email.ToString(), tbEmailCC.Text, tbEmailBC.Text, tbReplyTo.Text, DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.MailPriority.Normal,
                       tbSubject.Text, MailFormat.Html, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, tbEmailBody.Text, attachments, smtpServer, smtpAuthentication, smtpUsername, smtpPassword, false);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

                });
                RadRadialGauge1.Pointer.Value = count;
            }

            throw new SmtpException();
        }
    }
    catch (SmtpException smtp)
    {
        RadRadialGauge1.Pointer.Value = RadRadialGauge1.Pointer.Value - 1;
        var email = smtp.

        Exceptions.LogException(smtp);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exceptions.LogException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about wrapping the calls with a `try-catch`?

Comment: I am using a Try-Catch?

Comment: How to: Handle Exceptions in Parallel Loops
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd460695(v=VS.110).aspx)

Comment: Where are you using it?

Comment: Just posted the whole code section

Comment: @JohnAshton why do you ALWAYS throw a smtpexception at the end?

Comment: Oops just was tesing - thats why I am throwing it

Comment: BTW, you don't need `Parallel.ForEach`, you're just doing IO work. Look for the asynchronous API from `SmtpClient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a try catch as suggested by [Yuval Itzchakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870803/yuval-itzchakov). Then at the end `errorList` will be filled with all the emailaddresses that could not be send.

```
var errorList = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
Parallel.ForEach(emailList, email =>
{
     try
     {
         Mail.SendMail(tbEmailFrom.Text, email.ToString(), tbEmailCC.Text, tbEmailBC.Text, tbReplyTo.Text, DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.MailPriority.Normal,
         tbSubject.Text, MailFormat.Html, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, tbEmailBody.Text, attachments, smtpServer, smtpAuthentication, smtpUsername, smtpPassword, false);
         Interlocked.Increment(ref count);  
     }
     catch(SmtpException stmp)
     {
         Exceptions.LogException(smtp);
         errorList.Add(email);
     }   
});
RadRadialGauge1.Pointer.Value = count;
```

Comment: Better use ConcurrentQueue, or another thread save collection.

Comment: that would Hide the error, i'd throw a new exception that contains the eMail in the message and has the SMTP Exception as the inner exception unless of curse you can handle it in the catch making the error go away

Comment: @MrDywar You could also add `lock (errorList)` before adding to handle the concurrency issue.

Comment: @MrDywar agreed, ConcurrentBag will do just fine :)

Comment: @MikeT It does hide the error, but he can add extra logging. Ill edit to show.

Comment: @SynerCoder Still lose the connection between the email and the exception,

Comment: catch(SmtpException stmp)
     {
         throw new SmtpException ("Can't sent email " + email,stmp);
     } that would link the email and exception implicitly as well as preserving the current exception logic

Comment: Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd460695(v=VS.110).aspx. No need to throw anything.

Comment: @MikeT as I read the link from MrDywar it states: **an unhandled exception causes the loop to terminate immediately.**. Thus dont throw an exception, else not all mails will be send. And what do you mean with "Still lose the connection between the email and the exception." Depends on how his logging logic is.

Comment: @MrDywar i'm not saying that handler can't log the exception just that having separate and unlinked list of exceptions and emails doesn't provide the requested functionality as if multiple emails fail you can't tell which email failed for what reason, you could easily log the new exception instead of throwing it.. as long as doing so doesn't hide the error from a higher level process that requires it to do its own handling

Comment: @SynerCoder i think will be better to rewrite your code like on msdn sample, and use `Exception.Data` property to save e-mail string.

Comment: @SynerCoder that is correct, however that happens in the current process and the asker hasn't stated that he needs execution to continue after the error though i admit its a safe assumption, another option would be to save a tuple to errorList that has email and exception

Comment: Yes all the emails that can go must be sent

Comment: This worked - but I was using DotNetNuke method for sending email.  The exception was being caught within its source.  So I had to change code to use System.Net.Mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Visual Studio debugger (which I assume you are using) to break right when an exception is being thrown.

Open the Debug menu, click on the Exceptions item. Using the Find button, search for SmtpException, and click on the checkbox in the "Thrown" column. When you execute your program again, it will show you the exact moment when it happened, along with the callstack, local variables, etc.

Comment: That will not help the end -user determine if the email was sent or not

Comment: My apologies, the wording of your question implied you wanted to debug the issue, not inform the end-user.